# Solution for javascript variable name conflict other than iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop, codeigniter

im using Classy library for OOP programming in javascript.

i coded a class that handles canvas operations on a DIV element. Because of some difficulties in some parts of the code i had to use the object variable name within the class even though it is against the OOP approach.

for example:

```
drawer=new CanvasManager("div1",300,300);

var CanvasManager= Class.$extend({
    blabla:function()
{
    drawer.id=1;
}
});
```

Now i need to use this class more than once in one document on different DIVs and this conflict makes it impossible.Only solution i have is, using iframe elements to seperate them.

It was ok until i wanted to fetch iframe content from a **codeigniter view** instead of **controller**.

wanted to use something like this

```
<iframe  class="iframeclass1">
<?php
echo $this->load->view('gallery/w2',array('item'=>$amount),true);
?>
</iframe>
```

instead of

```
<iframe  class="iframeclass1" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/gallery/w2c/<?php echo $item->amount; ?>">
</iframe>
```

**So what other solution do we have to solve this object name conflict?**

**edit**:

if you ask why did you code it that way in the first place,some of the jquery functions doesnt let you to pass arguments( for instance each() ). actually only bind() function allows argument passing which helped a lot. if you know any solution for that i'd be glad.

**edit2**

the difficulty is this
lets say blabla function is like

```
blabla:function()
{
$('.somediv').each(function()
{
  $(this).html(drawer.id);
}
)
}
```

within each function "this" keyword becomes pointer for the jquery selector.

Comment: Can you give a fuller/clearer explanation for _why_ the variable name is `CanvasManager`?

Comment: it's not the class name that conflicts , it's object's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is to use javascript closures.
for instance:
http://jsfiddle.net/C7yen/

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
<script>
    obj={
       id:1,
        set:function()
        {
            setF=(function(ev){ return function(){ $(this).html(ev.id) } })(this);
            $('li').each(
    setF
    );
        }
    }
window.onload=function()
    {
obj.set()
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var appInstances = new array();
var keys = new array();
var id;

keys [0]['id'] = 'div1';
keys [0]['w'] = '300';
keys [0]['h'] = '300';
keys [1]['id'] = 'div2';

keys [1]['w'] = '300';
keys [1]['h'] = '300';

id  = 0;
appInstances[id] =CanvasManager(keys[id]['id'] , keys[id]['w'] , keys[id]['h']);
id  = 1;
appInstances[id] =CanvasManager(keys[id]['id'] , keys[id]['w'] , keys[id]['h']);

var CanvasManager= Class.$extend({
    blabla:function()
{
    appInstances[id].id=1;
}
});
```

Comment: the problem is when you use Jquery each function within class method , you loose access to object itself and you cant know what was its id.
lets say blabla function is like
blabla:function()
{
$('.somediv').each(function()
{ drawer.id=1; });

Comment: within each() function this keyword becomes selected html element, so you cant access id of the object itself

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class to manage the definition of your classes on the given divs. Also why give an entire class when you could create an object? Isn't this the main idea in OOP?

Comment: i didnt give class itself anywhere :/ it is the object that is given, drawer is the object , canvasmanager is the class.

Comment: i posted this when you hadn't yet edited your post. You could create a factory method in this case. And just set the div to what object you want.

Comment: i think you got it wrong, im not linking or creating new objects upon selected divs - $('.somediv') -. im just doing some operations on the innerhtml of those divs.

Comment: i got that, but you can set an initializer which passes through all your divs and construct in a itterator the object for the specified div than when you need div 5 you just do obj['div5'].draw while before that you do obj['div5'] = new CanvasManager("div5",300,300); so you know what object is on what, and have multiple objects of CanvasManager set on different divs with different varaiable name.

Comment: how blabla method is going to know it is called inside obj['div5'] when it has lost access to object itself inside each() call.

Comment: i mean you cant obj[this.div].draw() inside each() function because "this" becomes pointer to selected element with $('.somediv').